# [TestNG][Jar] Set Classpath in Manifest (Class-Path) -- classpath is ignored?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest, testng

I'm trying to run a simple TestNG test case residing within a jar file, which
contains the test and manifest:

ex.) Test.jar contains:
{
META-INF\
META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
tests\
tests\Test01.class
}

I am trying to run it using the command: java org.testng.TestNG -
testjar Test.jar testng.xml

Where a folder contains (all in the same directory):
Test.jar
testng.xml
testng-6.1.1.jar

And Manifest contains (w/ a line-break at the end):
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Willie Owens
Class-Path: testng-6.1.1.jar Test.jar .

And I get a NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG. Could not find
main class.

If I specify the classpath using -cp after "java" (Ex. java -cp
testng-6.1.1.jar;Test.jar org.testng.TestNG -testjar Test.jar
testng.xml) it works, but I want this information in the manifest.
What am I doing wrong here?

Also, I've tried every variation I could think of when typing in the Class-Path, such as: ./testng-6.1.1.jar .\testng-6.1.1.jar ...etc..

HELP

Comment: Had to reference Test.jar using -cp switch to work.. Ugly and not sure why its not by default, being the jar I am referencing in the command, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Executing test-jar is not that complex with testNg please refer [1] for more detail.

lease let me know if you find any pitfalls with it .

[1] http://dharshanaw.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-execute-testng-tests-in-side.html